# Facebook sdk v5 integration to codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I tried to integrate Facebook sdk v5 to my codeigniter project, by adding it to library and trying to override Facebook.php file but it didn't works. How can i integrate it in a correct way.
My goal is to get the number of likes from a page, i'm the administrator.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: https://benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/ I tried this tutorial

Comment: My goal is to get the number of likes from a page, i'm the administrator.

Comment: Details please: Linux or Windows server? Shared hosting? Local machine?

Answer (score 5):

I will suggest You to integrate using as a model . Unzip you facebook sdk . Put the unzipped folder in application/models . Rename the sdk folder to facebook .
Now you can use the following code to instantiate FB and get a kick-start . You can use this model for querying facebook .

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR',APPPATH.'/models/facebook/');

require_once("facebook/autoload.php");

        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
        use Facebook\GraphUser;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
        use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;



class facebook_model extends CI_Model 
{

public $fb ;
public $access_token ;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}



public function facebookInit()
{
      $this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                                     'app_id'                => 'APP_ID',
                                     'app_secret'            => 'APP_SECRET',
                                     'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
                                    ]); 
      return $this->fb ;                        

}
 //function to get login url for your app . Just create a controller which     handles redirects after facebook login 

public function loginUrl()
{
    $helper = $this->facebookInit()->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email','user_friends']; // Optional permissions

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(site_url()."/FBController/", $permissions);
    return $loginUrl ;  


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install php sdk v5 in codeigniter with composer https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v3-x-to-v5#installation-with-composer

create a controller and paste this code

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => 'app_id',
    'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
    'default_access_token' => 'access_token'
    ]);

    $response = $fb->get('/page_id');
    $body = $response->getBody();
```

$body is an array, send it to your views for show your data.